# Undefined error when capturing the time from SharePointList

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

[image]

[image]

I am trying to capture the time from SharePoint list using jquery, but it says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest is not a function when I try to store the hour field in a variable and then use it. I have attached both the images for reference.Also wanted to convert the time captured from sharepoint list i.e 02:00 PM to 24 hour format i.e 14:00. Requesting anyone to guide me how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following script:

Note: "time" is my date&time field name.

[image]

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {     
    // get time
    $("select[id^='time']").change(function(){
        var hours;
        var minutes;
        //get hours
        var hoursStr = $("select[id^='time'][id$='DateTimeFieldDateHours']").find("option:selected").text();
        minutes = $("select[id^='time'][id$='DateTimeFieldDateMinutes']").find("option:selected").text();
        if(hoursStr.includes("AM")){
            hours = parseInt(hoursStr,10);
        }else{
            hours = parseInt(hoursStr,10)+12;
        }
        console.log(hours+":"+minutes);
    });
});
</script>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the script, however I need to get the time captured in another change function. I do not want a fucntion. I just need to capture the hours and mins and convert into 24 hour time which is already selected.